# Ocaml syntax explanation please?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I'm new to Ocaml and I'm trying to figure out how this function works:

```
let ccc c1 c2 c3 = fun (s1, s2, s3) n ->
     let (t1, r1) = (c1 s1 2) in
        if r1 = 0
        then let (t2, r2) = (c2 s2 n) in ((t1, t2, s3), r2)
        else let (t3, r3) = (c3 s3 n) in ((t1, s2, t3), r3) ;;
```

`c1, c2, c3` are all "choosers".  I'm aware that the purpose of the function is to take 3 choosers in and let the first chooser pick which of the other two choosers to use, but I'm confused by the syntax.  Could anyone explain please?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer without knowing which part is confusing. Here are some simple examples that show some of the trickier parts.

```
# let f = fun x -> x + 1;;
val f : int -> int = <fun>
# f 3;;
- : int = 4
```

This defines `f` as a function that adds one to an integer. The expression `fun args -> expr` defines a function and the `let` binds the function to the name `f`.

```
# let f x = x + 1
val f : int -> int = <fun>
# f 3;;
- : int = 4
```

This defines the same function f. The meaning is exactly the same, it's just a slightly friendlier notation.

For whatever reason, your code is using *both* of these notations. I'm not sure I see a good reason to do this, but it does emphasize that if you pass three functions to `ccc` you'll get a function back.

The other pieces are pretty straightforward (though maybe they take some getting used to):

Function calls are formed just by writing things next to each other:

```
c1 s1 2
c2 s2 n
c3 s3 n
```

These are just calls to `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.

Tuples are formed using commas (and conventionally parentheses also). So `(t1, r1)` is a pair of values that is returned by the call to `c1`.

I assume you understand `if` / `then` / `else`, and `let` `in`. If not, they aren't hard to explain.

I'd actually suggest reading a tutorial on OCaml. It should be more efficient than asking questions one at a time on SO. There are good tutorials at [ocaml.org](http://ocaml.org).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I'm still confused as to what `s1, s2, s3` are.  And where does `n` come from?  Initially, we only pass `c1 c2 c3` to the `ccc` function right?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes `c2 s2 n` is a call to `c2` with two parameters, `s2` and `n`. `n` is the second argument of the inner function (the function starting with `fun`). And `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are the parts of the first argument (a 3-tuple) to the function that's returned by `ccc`.

Comment: So what exactly is passed to `ccc`?  Is it `c1 c2 c3` in addition to `(s1, s2, s3), n` ?

Comment: This is a tricky (and really cool) part of OCaml. If you don't want to get too deep into it, the answer is that ccc takes three arguments `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`, and it returns a *function*.  The function that it returns takes two arguments (a 3-tuple and a value named `n`).

Comment: OK I think that makes more sense.  Thank you :)